# How to fix ReplaceAll function in java code

Tags: java, replaceall

i am trying to replace all occurrences of the first character in a string with another using the replace all function. However, no change occurs when i run the function. I tried to target the first character of the original string and then carry the out the replacement but no luck. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
public static String charChangeAt(String str, String str2) {  

    //str = x.xy
    //str2 = d.w

    String res = str.replaceAll(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)), str2);

    return res ;
}
```

Comment: For me, `System.out.println(charChangeAt("d.dx", "d.w"));` outputs: `d.w.d.wx`. Something must be going wrong somewhere else. How are you calling this method?

Comment: i was trying to call it in a loop. So basically i'm cycling through an array of strings and changing occurrences of the first character to something else for the string in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code replaces all characters that match the first character. If your string is `abcda` and you run your function, it will replace all occurences of `a` with whatever you put. Including the last one.

To achieve your goal you should probably not use `replaceAll`.

You could use `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
myName.setCharAt(0, str2.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine but you probably are using  it the wrong way. 
For these strings:

```
String str = "abaca";
String str2 = "x";
```

if you do:

```
charChangeAt(str, str2);
```

this will not affect `str`. 
You must assign the value returned by your function to `str`:

```
str = charChangeAt(str, str2);
```

This will change the value of `str` to:

```
"xbxcx"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to replace all occurrences of the first character in a string with another, you can use **replace** instead of **replaceAll**. Below is the code snippet.

```
String str = "x.xy";
String str2 = "d.w";
String res = str.replace(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)), str2);
return res; // will output d.w.d.wy
```